# Ansible: can't del user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible, userdel

I'm trying del user with the same name on all my servers.
I'm using

```
 ansible all -m user -a "name=tim-g state=absent remove=yes" -s
```

After this, system ask me the sudo password, but it's no work, I get:

```
192.168.170.150 | FAILED >> {
"failed": true,
"msg": "userdel: Permission denied.\nuserdel: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.\n",
"name": "tim-g",
"rc": 1
}
192.168.170.151 | FAILED >> {
"failed": true,
"msg": "userdel: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.\n",
"name": "tim-g",
"rc": 1
}
```

and same on all other servers.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [http://superuser.com/](http://superuser.com/) a partner stackexchange site.

Comment: even if it stayed on stackoverflow, more information is needed- add `-vvvv` debugging and paste it here, show how you are using `sudo`, etc.

Comment: @tedder42, log with -vvvv http://pastebin.com/3vu68dzR

Comment: the answer by @tendo is correct. Your username ('exad') doesn't have permission to delete. You should be running as root or with sudo.

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the return message that the user from which you are login doesn't have permission to delete/remove other user, for this you can modify this command and login with the user that has permission to perform this task:

For example:

```
ansible all -m user -a "name=tim-g state=absent remove=yes" -u USERNAME -K
```

where `USERNAME`, is any user with sudo permission

`-K` ask for sudo password

If you are using `-s`, then your sudo user can only perform these operations if he/she had configured for nopasswd sudo.

Hope that will help you. Thanks